# Matplotlib boxplot show only max and min fliers

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am making standard Matplotlib boxplots using the plt.boxplot() command.
My line of code that creates the boxplot is:

```
bp = plt.boxplot(data, whis=[5, 95], showfliers=True)
```

Because my data has a large distribution, I am getting a lot of fliers outside the range of the whiskers. To get a cleaner publication quality plot, I would like to only show single fliers at the max. and at the min. values of the data, instead of all fliers. Is this possible? I don't see any built-in options in the documentation to do this.

(I can set the range of the whiskers to max/min, but this is not what I want. I would like to keep the whiskers at the 5th and 95th percentiles).

Below is the figure I am working on. Notice the density of fliers.
[image: Boxplots]

Comment: Isn't that density of fliers important information?

Comment: Yes, definitely is. Depends on what you are trying to show I suppose. But you make a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.boxplot()` returns a dictionary, where the key `fliers` contains the upper and lower fliers as line2d objects. You can manipulate them before plotting like this:

**Only on matplotlib >= 1.4.0**

```
bp = plt.boxplot(data, whis=[5, 95], showfliers=True)

# Get a list of Line2D objects, representing a single line from the
# minimum to the maximum flier points.
fliers = bp['fliers']

# Iterate over it!
for fly in fliers:
    fdata = fly.get_data()
    fly.set_data([fdata[0][0],fdata[0][-1]],[fdata[1][0],fdata[1][-1]])
```

**On older versions**

If you are on an older version of matplotlib, the fliers for each boxplot are represented by *two* lines, not one. Thus, the loop would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(len(fliers)):
    fdata = fliers[i].get_data()
    # Get the index of the maximum y in data if 
    # i is 0 or even, else get index of minimum y.
    if i%2 == 0:
        id = np.where(fdata[1] == fdata[1].max())[0][0]
    else:
        id = np.where(fdata[1] == fdata[1].min())[0][0]
    fliers[i].set_data([fdata[0][id], fdata[1][id]])
```

Also note that the `showfliers` argument doesn't exist in matplotlib <1.4x and the `whisk` argument doesn't accept lists.

Of course (for simple applications) you could plot the boxplot without fliers and add the max and min points to the plot:

```
bp = plt.boxplot(data, whis=[5, 95], showfliers=False)
sc = plt.scatter([1, 1], [data.min(), data.max()])
```

where `[1, 1]` is the x-position of the points.

Comment: Your first solution plots all the max fliers just fine, but not the min. If I sub in min for max in the code, then just the mins plot. Maybe I am missing something, but how do I get both the max and the min to plot? The second suggested solution does not work....plots some points below the boxes, but they are not the mins. And the third suggested solution won't work for me, as 'data' is actually a list of many Pandas dataframes (producing multiple boxplots as in the posted figure). Thanks for your answer though, I think it is very close!

Comment: Sorry, was a bit too late yesterday. I fixed it above. Hope it's reasonably explicit and easy to follow. Also took the second suggestion out.

Comment: Now, the min and max alternate, such that box 1 shows just the max, box 2 shows just the min, box 3 shows just the max, etc...... ?? See the figure I added above.

Comment: This works for me on multiple boxplots without problem...what matplotlib version are you on?

Comment: This definitely looks like a version problem with the update to mpl 1.4x I'll update it above soon.

Comment: I ended up exploring this further, and posted my solution as an answer. Thanks much for getting me on the right track though! I am using matplotlib==1.4.0

Comment: You may want to place the the last line in a try:…except IndexError:… in case there is no fliers for some boxes.

Answer (score 3):

```
fliers = bp['fliers'] 
for i in range(len(fliers)): # iterate through the Line2D objects for the fliers for each boxplot
    box = fliers[i] # this accesses the x and y vectors for the fliers for each box 
    box.set_data([[box.get_xdata()[0],box.get_xdata()[0]],[np.min(box.get_ydata()),‌​np.max(box.get_ydata())]]) 
    # note that you can use any two values from the xdata vector
```

Resulting figure, showing only max and min fliers:
[image]