# dc.js Boxplots displaying values

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Has anyone added the ability to display values in a boxplot for dc.js?

Interesting answer given to this question related to matplotlib.
[Adding a scatter of points to a boxplot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779079/adding-a-scatter-of-points-to-a-boxplot-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

As it's currently implemented, the box plot will display any outliers as circles, and outliers are defined as the points which do not fall within the whiskers.

If you're willing to change the source, it's pretty easy to disable the whiskers and show all the data points.

You just need to change line 42:

```
var _whiskers = _whiskersIqr(_whiskerIqrFactor);
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/356fccea3a1dbd49a76fb1841f280ffad87d725f/src/box-plot.js#L42

You could just set it to `null`, or add an accessor for whiskers. (There really should be one, looks like an oversight.)

It looks like this with no whiskers:

[image: box plot no whiskers]

You'd have to dig a bit deeper and [change the underlying d3-plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/box/box.js) if you want to display whiskers along with the data points.