# boxplot show max and min fliers results in TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am preparing box plots with a whisker interval of `[2,98]`. The issue is that I am working with air quality data and have a large range of data points, so the outliers take up the entire figure and overshadow the boxplots. I would like to plot the **max and min outliers only** and have tried the method from [Matplotlib boxplot show only max and min fliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521828/matplotlib-boxplot-show-only-max-and-min-fliers), however, I get an error message that says `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable`.

Here is my code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,6))
g = sns.boxplot(data=mda8, orient='v', width = 0.7, whis = (2,98))
fliers = g['fliers']
for fly in fliers:
    fdata=fly.get_data
    fly.set_data([fdata[0][0],fdata[0][-1],fdata[1][0],fdata[1][-1]])
xvalues = ['Niland', 'El Centro', 'Calexico']
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), xvalues, fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Ozone MDA8 (ppb)',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylim(0,105)
plt.show()
```

Here's some sample data:

```
mda8 = pd.DataFrame({
'T1':[35.000000, 32.125000, 32.000000, 35.250000, 28.875000, 28.500000, 29.375000, 25.125000, 34.166667, 35.250000],
'T2':[28.375, 30.750, 33.250, 34.000, 32.875, 30.250, 29.875, 100.409, 29.625, 1.232],
'T3':[34.250, 102.232, 28.250, 33.000, 27.625, 21.500, 28.375, 30.250, 3.454, 33.750]})
```

I need help with plotting the **max and min outliers only** and am open to doing another method besides the one that I tried here.

**EDIT** here's the link to my csv file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3A0UAYCbSN53JXtfsbrA4i_Phci_JWf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach could be:

- hide the outliers plotted by `seaborn.boxplot` by passing `showfliers = False` parameter:

  ```
  sns.boxplot(data=mda8, orient='v', width = 0.7, whis = (2,98), showfliers = False)
  ```
- get the list of outliers for each column, find maximum and minimum and plot only them:

  ```
  outliers = {col: list(stat['fliers']) for col in mda8.columns for stat in boxplot_stats(mda8[col])}
  min_max_outliers = {key: [np.min(value), np.max(value)] if value != [] else [] for key, value in outliers.items()}

  i = 0
  for key, value in min_max_outliers.items():
      if value != []:
          ax.scatter([i, i], value, marker = 'd', facecolor = 'black')
      i += 1
  ```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.cbook import boxplot_stats


mda8 = pd.DataFrame({'T1': [35.000000, 32.125000, 32.000000, 35.250000, 28.875000, 28.500000, 29.375000, 25.125000, 34.166667, 35.250000],
                     'T2': [28.375, 30.750, 33.250, 34.000, 32.875, 30.250, 29.875, 100.409, 29.625, 1.232],
                     'T3': [34.250, 102.232, 28.250, 33.000, 27.625, 21.500, 28.375, 30.250, 3.454, 33.750]})


fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,6))

sns.boxplot(data=mda8, orient='v', width = 0.7, whis = (2,98), showfliers = False)

outliers = {col: list(stat['fliers']) for col in mda8.columns for stat in boxplot_stats(mda8[col])}
min_max_outliers = {key: [np.min(value), np.max(value)] if value != [] else [] for key, value in outliers.items()}

i = 0
for key, value in min_max_outliers.items():
    if value != []:
        ax.scatter([i, i], value, marker = 'd', facecolor = 'black')
    i += 1

xvalues = ['Niland', 'El Centro', 'Calexico']
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), xvalues, fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Ozone MDA8 (ppb)',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylim(0,105)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

Working on the data your provided, if I plot them as they are:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


mda8 = pd.read_csv(r'data/MDA8_allregions.csv')
mda8 = mda8.drop(['date', 'date.1', 'date.2'], axis = 1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (8, 6))

sns.boxplot(data = mda8, orient = 'v', width = 0.7, whis = (2, 98), showfliers = True)

plt.show()
```

I get:

[image]

In the code above I change the parameter `showfliers = False`, in order to hide outliers.
Then, as suggested by JohanC in the comment, a simpler way to plot outliers is to plot min and max for each column:

```
for i, col in enumerate(mda8.columns, 0):
    ax.scatter([i, i], [mda8[col].min(), mda8[col].max()], marker = 'd', facecolor = 'black')
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


mda8 = pd.read_csv(r'data/MDA8_allregions.csv')
mda8 = mda8.drop(['date', 'date.1', 'date.2'], axis = 1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (8, 6))

sns.boxplot(data = mda8, orient = 'v', width = 0.7, whis = (2, 98), showfliers = False)

for i, col in enumerate(mda8.columns, 0):
    ax.scatter([i, i], [mda8[col].min(), mda8[col].max()], marker = 'd', facecolor = 'black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This code is not working for me. I don't get an error message but I also don't get any max and min points on my figures.

Comment: Please, can you provide your dataframe?

Comment: A simplification could be to ignore the outlier test and just use the min and max of each column instead of `boxplot_stats`. E.g. `min_max_outliers = {col: [mda8[col].min(), mda8[col].max()] for col in mda8.columns}`

Comment: is there a way I can include a csv file? The dataframe is over 4000 rows.

Comment: You could upload it on a google drive folder and share the link

Comment: okay @Zephyr I uploaded the link in my submission

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly, let me know if it meets your requirements